# Differences in ctypes between Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, dll, numpy, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a working python 2.7 program that calls a DLL. I am trying to port the script to python 3.2. The DLL call seems to work (i.e. there is no error upon calling) but the returned data does not make sense.

Just in case it could be useful:
- The call takes three arguments: two int (input) and a pointer to a ushort array (output).

I have tried using both python and numpy arrays without success.

Can anyone enumerate the differences between Python 2.7 and 3.2 respecting ctypes?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is some example code. The DLL is propietary so I do not have the code. But I do have the C header:

```
void example (int width, int height, unsigned short* pointer)
```

The python code is:

```
width, height = 40, 100
imagearray = np.zeros((width,height), dtype=np.dtype(np.ushort))
image = np.ascontiguousarray(imagearray)
ptrimage = image.ctypes.data_as(ct.POINTER(ct.c_ushort))
DLL.example(width, height, ptrimage)
```

This works in python 2.7 but not in 3.2.

**EDIT 2**

If the changes in ctypes are only those pointed out by Cedric, it does not make sense that python 3.2 will not work. So looking again at the code, I have found that there is a preparation function called before the function that I am mentioning. The signature is:

```
void prepare(char *table)
```

In python, I am calling by:

```
table = str(aNumber)
DLL.prepare(table)
```

Is it possible that the problem is due to the change in the Python string handling?

Comment: I'm not aware of any differences at all. I think we'd need to see some code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Python 2.7, strings are byte-strings by default. In Python 3.x, they are unicode by default. Try explicitly making your string a byte string using `.encode('ascii')` before handing it to `DLL.prepare`.

**Edit:**

```
#another way of saying table=str(aNumber).encode('ascii')
table = bytes(str(aNumber), 'ascii')
DLL.prepare(table)
```

Comment: Several years on, this answer is very useful! I also had an issue where I was using an old python library in Python3 and couldn't understand why the code wasn't working. After changing the strings I pass to the shared library to be ascii, everything worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

In our case, we had code looking like:

```
addr = clib.some_function()
data = some_struct.from_address(addr)
```

This worked in python 2 but not in 3. The reason turned out not to be any difference in ctypes, but rather a change in memory layout that unmasked a bug in the code above. In python 2, the address returned was always (by chance) small enough to fit inside a C int (32-bit), which is the default return type for all ctypes function calls. In python 3, the addresses were almost always too large, which caused the pointer address to become corrupted as it was coerced to int.

The solution is to set the function `restype` to a 64-bit integer type to ensure that it can accommodate the whole address, like:

```
clib.some_function.restype = c_longlong
```

or:

```
clib.some_function.restype = POINTER(some_struct)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the python documentation, the only changes between 2.7 and 3.2 [is here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.2.html#ctypes)

> A new type, ctypes.c_ssize_t represents the C ssize_t datatype.

In 2.7, there was some other [modifications introduced](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.7.html#new-and-improved-modules) :

> The ctypes module now always converts None to a C NULL pointer for
>   arguments declared as pointers. (Changed by Thomas Heller; issue
>   4606.) The underlying libffi library has been updated to version
>   3.0.9, containing various fixes for different platforms. (Updated by
>   Matthias Klose; issue 8142.)

I'm not sure it will explain the cause of your problem...