# Python3 segfaults when using ctypes on xlib, python2 works

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, xlib

The following code was scrounged up on the Internet years ago and works quite well in python2. It supplies the current idle time on the X server.

```
import ctypes, os, subprocess
class XScreenSaverInfo( ctypes.Structure ):
    _fields_ = [("window",     ctypes.c_ulong), ("state",      ctypes.c_int), ("kind",       ctypes.c_int), ("since",      ctypes.c_ulong), ("idle",       ctypes.c_ulong), ("event_mask", ctypes.c_ulong)]

xlib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libX11.so.6")
xss = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libXss.so.1")
display = xlib.XOpenDisplay(os.environ["DISPLAY"])
xss.XScreenSaverAllocInfo.restype = ctypes.POINTER(XScreenSaverInfo)
xssinfo = xss.XScreenSaverAllocInfo()

 xss.XScreenSaverQueryInfo(display, xlib.XDefaultRootWindow(display), xssinfo)

 xssinfo.contents.idle
```

I can throw this into a python2.7.10 shell and get what I want. However, doing the same on a python3.4.3 shell kicks me out with a segmentation fault in this line

```
xss.XScreenSaverQueryInfo(display, xlib.XDefaultRootWindow(display), xssinfo)
```

Is my py3 environment broken? Does py3 do something differently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was no significant change in Python 3's `ctypes` module. *However* in Python3 `os.environ` values are *unicode* strings, contrary to the byte strings of python2 and this [causes the segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256283/differences-in-ctypes-between-python-2-and-3). So changing:

```
display = xlib.XOpenDisplay(os.environ["DISPLAY"])
```

To:

```
display = xlib.XOpenDisplay(bytes(os.environ["DISPLAY"], 'ascii'))
```

Fixes the segmentation fault.

If you want to have code that works both in python 2 and 3 you want to use the `encode` method:

```
display = xlib.XOpenDisplay(os.environ["DISPLAY"].encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the case!

Comment: @Bakuriu Still segfaults for me at xlib.XDefaultRootWindow(display)

Comment: I suspect it has to do with gtk, as it is working on KDE for me

Comment: @cass That's probably an other unrelated issue. I suggest you open a new question, specifying precisely your OS configuration and how it affects the behaviour of the program.

Comment: @cass you ever solve that other segfault?