# Python 2.7 to 3.5: What changed with ctypes?

Tags: c, python-3.x

The following small program is calling a C lib:

```
from ctypes import * 

ini_file="/home/pi/pyYASDI/yasdi.ini"
yasdiMaster_lib="/usr/local/lib/libyasdimaster.so"

masterlib = cdll.LoadLibrary(yasdiMaster_lib)

DriverCount=c_ulong(10)
pDriverCount=byref(DriverCount)
print("Init: ",masterlib.yasdiMasterInitialize(ini_file,pDriverCount))
```

In Python 2.7 the C lib call is working fine, in Python 3.5 it's returning a different value. Unfortunately I am unable to debug the C lib. What is changing from 2.7 to 3.5 in that small code? Will there be a change handing over the arguments to the C lib? The arguments of the `yasdiMasterInitialize` call are `char * cIniFileName, DWORD * pDriverCount)`.

Comment: Do you mean the return value of `yasdiMasterInitialize` or the value that is written to `pDriverCount`? What are the two values? Which of the values did you expect to get?

Comment: The  `yasdiMasterInitialize` call in the last line is returning a 0 in 2.7, but a -1 in 3.5. It doesn't matter what the lib call is actually doing - the questions is why is it different?

Comment: In C, a return value of 0 typically means "success" and -1 "failure". You should look up the documentation of `yasdiMasterInitialize` to be sure and to get hints about what could be a cause for failure.

Comment: I am calling the same C lib with the same call and the same arguments. But something must be different because `yasdiMasterInitialize` is not working in 3.5. The arguments for `yasdiMasterInitialize` are `(char * cIniFileName, DWORD * pDriverCount)`

Comment: Maybe the difference is how strings are handled in Python 2 and 3, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256283/differences-in-ctypes-between-python-2-and-3

Comment: Are you certain you're still using the same version of `libyadimaster.so`? Does that library provide any additional information in the event that a function call fails (like many C library calls set `errno` to indicate the nature of the error)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hint! It is the Unicode change of Python 3.5! I changed only one line now:

```
ini_file="/home/pi/pyYASDI/yasdi.ini".encode('ascii')
```