# Why do I get different output running the same code on different python versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

So I've been learning the ctypes library when I came to an unexpected result.

I have following code just to test that ctypes works properly:

```
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL("libc.so.6")
message_string = "Hello world!\n"
libc.printf("Testing: %s", message_string)
```

I ran it with python2.7 and python3, when it seemed like there should be same results though the versions are different.

```
root@Crushli-pc ~# python3 --version && python --version
Python 3.7.5
Python 2.7.17
root@Crushli-pc ~# python chapter1-printf.py 
Testing: Hello world!
root@Crushli-pc ~# python3 chapter1-printf.py 
T⏎                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         root@Crushli-pc ~#
```

I *do* know that python2 support has ended with the beginning of this year, that's why I'm curious about why python3 doesn't work as intented.

The machine I've been running code on:

```
..............                                     root@Crushli-pc 
            ..,;:ccc,.                             --------------- 
          ......''';lxO.                           OS: Kali GNU/Linux Roll 
.....''''..........,:ld;                           Kernel: 5.3.0-kali2-amd 
           .';;;:::;,,.x,                          Uptime: 1 hour, 21 mins 
      ..'''.            0Xxoc:,.  ...              Packages: 2226 (dpkg) 
  ....                ,ONkc;,;cokOdc',.            Shell: bash 5.0.11 
 .                   OMo           ':ddo.          Resolution: 1080x1920,  
                    dMc               :OO;         DE: Xfce 
                    0M.                 .:o.       WM: Xfwm4 
                    ;Wd                            WM Theme: Kali-Dark 
                     ;XO,                          Theme: Kali-Dark [GTK2/ 
                       ,d0Odlc;,..                 Icons: Flat-Remix-Blue- 
                           ..',;:cdOOd::,.         Terminal: qterminal 
                                    .:d;.':;.      Terminal Font: Fira Cod 
                                       'd,  .'     CPU: Intel i5-3570 (4)  
                                         ;l   ..   GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 
                                          .o       Memory: 1791MiB / 7922M 
                                            c
                                            .'                             
                                             .
```

I will provide any information needed, just ask about it, please.

My question is *what* am i doing wrong and *why* it doesn't work properly now.

**EDIT:**
Tried this --> [Differences in ctypes between Python 2 and 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256283/differences-in-ctypes-between-python-2-and-3), and got the code like this:

```
from ctypes import *                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

msvcrt = CDLL("libc.so.6")                                                                                                                                                                                                             
message_string = str("Hello world!\n").encode('ascii')                                                                                                                                                                                 
msvcrt.printf("Testing: %s", message_string)
```

Still, I got the same results:

```
root@Crushli-pc ~# cat chapter1-printf.py 
from ctypes import *

msvcrt = CDLL("libc.so.6")
message_string = str("Hello world!\n").encode('ascii')
msvcrt.printf("Testing: %s", message_string)
root@Crushli-pc ~# python3 chapter1-printf.py 
T⏎                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         root@Crushli-pc ~# python chapter1-printf.py 
Testing: Hello world!
root@Crushli-pc ~#
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256283/differences-in-ctypes-between-python-2-and-3 The accepted answer to this question might be helpful to you, it explains the way Python 2 and Python 3 handle ctypes differently.

Comment: @Sciborg thanks for your response, I've looked through the question, and actually it is an answer to my question. But it's interesting to note that one thing is different. I get bad-encoded results whilst using the `.encode("ascii")` and the right ones when I use `.encode('utf8')`, what was mentioned by this question answerer. Thanks for your response alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `printf` is expecting a bytes string, you should encode your strings before passing them:

```
 libc.printf("Testing with non-ascii chars abc€ éю: %s".encode('utf8'),
             message_string.encode('utf8'))
```

Output:

```
Testing with non-ascii chars abc€ éю: Hello world!
```

Comment: Caveat: Only works if printf expects UTF-8-encoded strings.  This wouldn't work on Windows for example.